# Conditional Formatting multiple rows in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck on a conditional formatting question. So I have a dynamic calendar template in which you can change month and week etc. The dates only range from column E to column X. It looks like this:[image]

The 11th row is the date row, and the orange cells are dates which are holidays. The conditional formatting to color those cells is:

```
=COUNTIF(holiday,E$11)>0
```

[image]

where holiday is a named range containing the list of holidays.
What I would like to do is color the rows below as well when the date is a holiday. So in this case, if 13th may is a holiday, I12:I17 should also be colored orange.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Edit: As @SRA suggested, if I select the whole E11:X17, it solves my problem halfway as posted: 
[image]

What I also wanted was to get rid of the text which is coming through conditional formatting, not the text of the date which is the 11th row, but the text of the below rows if its a holiday.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select the entire range I12:I17 and then apply the conditional formatting

EDIT:

Do the following 2 steps

1) Selec I11 and apply the below formatting

(ONLY BACKGROUND IS ORANGE)

[image]

2) Select I12 : I17 and apply the below formatting

(BAKGROUND and FONT both orange)

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question, can you help with the remaining part as well? Thanks a lot

Comment: Conditional formatting cannot edit cell values. Perhaps, you could use this formula in the cells I13:I17 :   =IF(COUNTIF(holidays,$I$11)>0,I12)

Comment: Even if we cant edit the cell values, we can hide it by coloring the text and background same? But I dont want to hide the date values in 11th row by this method. Thanks

Comment: You can then use two different sets of conditional formattings, First, Only select I11 and apply the conditional formatting where in you color the background orange Second, Select I12:I17 and apply condtional formatting where in background color = orange and text color = orange

Comment: what should be the formula for the range I12:X17? Sorry, I am new to VBA.